# preg_match() []: Unknown modifier '/' after php upgrade from 5.2 to 5.3

Tags: php, preg-match

```
 118:   function validateString($string, $maxlength, $minlength, $er) {
 119:   if (strlen($string) < $minlength or strlen($string) > $maxlength or !preg_match("/" . $er . "/i", $string)) {
 120:       return FALSE;
 121:   } else {
 122:       return TRUE;
```

Since an upgrade to php 5.3 (from 5.2), line 119 is causing the error `preg_match() []: Unknown modifier '/'`.

Thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Escape special characters in `$er` with function [preg_quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php):

```
$re = preg_quote($er);
```